# Generalization of even-odd parity (symmetry) decomposition of 2-dim functions

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, functional-analysis, reference-request, even-and-odd-functions

For any "well-behaving" real-valued (1-dim) function $f(x)$, the following decomposition that can always be done is basic and at the same time very useful.
$$f(x) = f_{ev}(x) + f_{od}(x) \qquad \begin{cases}
\text{even:}& f_{ev}(x):= \frac{1}2 \left( f(x) + f(-x) \right) \\
\text{odd:}& f_{od}(x):= \frac{1}2 \left( f(x) - f(-x) \right) 
\end{cases}$$
It is ubiquitous in analysis for PDE (orthonormal basis), integral equations, and sometimes functional equations.

> 1. Where can I find a exposition/discussion on a 2-dim analogue (generalization) that is powerful in a similar way? In particular, I assume for 2-dim some **geometrical considerations** should be prominent.
> 2. If no such material readily available, what might be some good use or issues with my try below?

The generalization briefly mentioned in the second half of [Wolfram Mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EvenFunction.html) entry or the section in [wikipeida](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Even_and_odd_functions#Generalizations) is kind of boring, and in my opinion no where near "complete".

### My try to construct something similar to orthogonal basis:

Here the term "even" is generally understood as "symmetric" for the relevant transformation, and "odd" is understood as "anti-symmetric".
$$\begin{aligned}
f_{Rev}(x,y) &:= \frac16 \left( f(x,y) - f(-x,-y) \right) \qquad \text{"R" for rotation by $\pi$ WRT...}\\
f_{Rod}(x,y) &:= \frac16 \left( f(x,y) - f(-x,-y) \right) \qquad \text{... (with respect to) the origin}\\
f_{Xev}(x,y) &:= \frac16 \left( f(x,y) + f(-x,y) \right) \\
f_{Xod}(x,y) &:= \frac16 \left( f(x,y) - f(-x,y) \right) \qquad \text{reflection WRT $y$-axis} \\
f_{Yev}(x,y) &:= \frac16 \left( f(x,y) + f(x,-y) \right) \\
f_{Yod}(x,y) &:= \frac16 \left( f(x,y) - f(x,-y) \right) \qquad \text{reflection WRT $x$-axis} \\
\end{aligned}$$
These piece are sort of "orthogonal" just like in 1-dim how the sign function (the "core" of odd functions) is orthogonal to the constant function as in $\int 1 \cdot \mathrm{sign}(x) dx = 0$.

The decomposition of "any" 2-dim function then looks like
$$f = f_{Rev} + f_{Rod} + f_{Xev} + f_{Xod} + f_{Yev} + f_{Yod}$$
with the behavior the individual components analogous to the 1-dim case:
$$\begin{aligned}
f_{Rev}(x,y) &= f_{Rev}(-x,-y) \\
f_{Rod}(x,y) &= -f_{Rod}(-x,-y) \\
f_{Xev}(x,y) &= f_{Xev}(-x,y) \\
f_{Xod}(x,y) &= -f_{Xod}(-x,y) \\
f_{Yev}(x,y) &= f_{Yev}(x,-y) \\
f_{Yod}(x,y) &= -f_{Yod}(x,-y) \\
\end{aligned}$$
The above seems okay, but I feel like either something's missing or there are actually already redundancies.

The missing components might are the "prominent **geometrical considerations**" I mentioned above, which might include rotation by $\pi/2$ and by $3\pi/2$.

The redundancy part is I'm not so sure how to deal with the fact that "rotate by $\pi$ with respect to the origin" is equivalent to the composition "[reflection WRT $x$-axis]$\circ$[reflection WRT $y$-axis]".

Comment: Odd and even generalise to functions between vector spaces.